# Error: positional arguments are not supported

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

```
[program:sam_reports_uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini /var/www/phis-ng/server_config/staging_wsgi.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile=/var/log/sam_reports/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/sam_reports/stderr.log
user=ubuntu
directory=/var/www/phis-ng/src/imam
```

This is the conf file I have for supervisord but when I try to run `supervisord staging_supervisor.conf` in the folder it is located, it gives me this error:

`Error: positional arguments are not supported`

I can't see what I am doing wrong comparing it against what I've found via Google and supervisord docs. I'm using supervisord 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

to

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Unfortunately cannot yet explain why that helps.

Comment: `CMD` might be ignored when container runs with a command, e.g. `docker run -it IMAGE /bin/bash` so this solution might be very confusing and hard to debug. You can see my reply for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing `ENTYRPOINT` with `CMD` is kind of *slick* solution, because when container runs with a command, e.g. `docker run -it IMAGE /bin/bash`, `CMD` is ignored. It may work for small Dockerfiles, but in bigger with many layers it could be very hard to debug. But I found a solution to use `ENTRYPOINT` with `supervisord` avoiding error *positional arguments are not supported* error. 
Just put `supervisord` command in shell script `.sh`, copy that to container and then use `ENTRYPOINT` on that file, e.g.:

**run_supervisord.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY image_scripts/run_supervisord.sh /opt/bin/run_supervisord.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/opt/bin/run_supervisord.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `supervisord` running as a daemon and try `supervisorctl` for each program instead.

For ubuntu, create `/etc/supervisord/conf.d/some_app.conf` file which contains `[program:some_app]` section.

Then, start it.

```
supervisorctl reload
supervisorctl start some_app
```

Confirm it's running

```
supervisorctl status
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `-c` before your config file. It thinks the config file is a 'positional argument'.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow, supervisord requires *CMD* instruction. So, you may write like whis:

```
CMD []
ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```